# How do I horizontally align a table and an image

Tags: css, html

I have tried an endless amount of possibilities to try and come to a conclusion, as well as hours of research, but cannot find an answer to this question!

I want to be able to have an image inline with a table of links. this is what i have tried..

html:

```
<p class="firstpic"><img src="trout.jpg">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> <a href="flies.html">Flies</a> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <a href="rodreels.html">Rod And Reel </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <a href="clothes.html"> Clothing </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <a href="shoes.html"> Footwear </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <a href="bait.html"> Baits And Lures </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <a href="gifts.html"> Gifts </th>
    </tr>
</table>
</p>
```

css:

```
p.firstpic {
text-align: center;
}
```

The end result gives me a centered image, while the table is stuck below and left of said image. Please help me as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- Be sure to close all of your anchor tags in the table, as you only close the first one.
- Consider putting your picture and table in a div, rather than a p tag, as divs are more traditionally used for grouping items together.

Now on to the positioning:

I'd recommend placing the image and table in one div and assign the float property to the image, which will keep the image and table together (as they're in a div) and should display them in line.
HTML:

```
<div class="firstpic">
    <img src="trout.jpg">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th> <a href="flies.html">Flies</a> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> <a href="rodreels.html">Rod And Reel</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> <a href="clothes.html">Clothing</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> <a href="shoes.html">Footwear</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> <a href="bait.html">Baits And Lures</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> <a href="gifts.html">Gifts</a></th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.firstpic {
    text-align: center;
}

.firstpic img {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: this works for the most part, but there are now two errors i have come across. one problem is, i still need to have the table and image separated but inline as they are. and the second thing is, the copyright that I have at the bottom of the page moves up inline with the image instead of staying at the bottom.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by separate, but you can always put them in nested divs to keep them separate in terms of code (put a pair of div tags around the image and a pair around the table but within the outermost div).

If you mean that you want them visually father apart, you can use the margin CSS property.  put 'margin-left: ##px;' in the '.firstpic img' section of your CSS (replacing ## with a numerical value).

To move the copyright to the bottom, try setting it's style to "clear: both."  That forces it to be below floating objects and should move it back to the bottom.

Comment: And by margin-left, I meant margin-right.  Margin-left will increase the margin on the left side of the picture (rather than the right, which is what I think you actually want). Funny how telling my left from my right is harder than creating and styling a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are just trying to center the table's content as well? If so, just add `table {margin: auto;}`. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEPpd/)

Answer (score 0):

try Divs,

```
<div class="firstpic"><div style="float:left"><img src="trout.jpg"></div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> <a href="flies.html">Flies</a> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <a href="rodreels.html">Rod And Reel </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <a href="clothes.html"> Clothing </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <a href="shoes.html"> Footwear </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <a href="bait.html"> Baits And Lures </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> <a href="gifts.html"> Gifts </th>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And work on CSS to adjust alignment.

Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can add float property to your paragraph. Also close all your anchor tags. Symmetrically it's not correct.

```
p.firstpic {
text-align: center;
    float:left;
}
```

[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/LEPpd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Add align center to your table like below.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0" align="center">
```